# Why does phpDoc opening sequence have two stars in `/**` instead of just `/*`

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Things seem quite visually and machine-parseably clear with just `/*`

https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html should say something about this, but doesn't.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I'd guess to be able to separate them from regular multiline comments.

Comment: With PhpStorm when you type `/**[space]` before a method, the IDE infers the structure of the phpdocs and suggests the appropriate types, vars, returns, throws, etc... in of itself a very useful feature. It sure is helpful for code analysis/creation tools, but i'm not certain that was the reason behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a regular php comment (`/* ... */`) and a [DocBlock](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html) (`/** ... */`) (or [PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc)).

PHP Interprets both as comments, however when using IDE's - they can parse the DocBlocks and provide you a better programming experience (with type-hints and autocomplets), and if you want you can use them to export a complete documentation of your code (packages/classes/functions/etc).

If you take for example this code:

```
<?php
 /**
  * A summary informing the user what the associated element does.
  *
  * A *description*, that can span multiple lines, to go _in-depth_ into the details of this element
  * and to provide some background information or textual references.
  *
  * @param string $myArgument With a *description* of this argument, these may also
  *    span multiple lines.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  function myFunction($myArgument)
  {
  }
```

You can see that the function `myFunction` doesn't return anything (`@return void`) and it only accepts one parameter (`$myArgument`) which supposed to be a string.

To export a complete documentation you can use the [phpDocumentor tool](https://phpdoc.org/).

Comment: As an aside, I'm fairly sure the `/**` convention was inherited from `javadoc` syntax.